# Git switch branch without commiting and transferring the changes on the current branch

Tags: git

I have a feature branch and a master branch, and I was doing something on a feature branch and made changes to some files. Now, I would like to go back to master branch with keeping the changes in the current feature branch, but withouth commiting them or transferring them to the master branch. If I do

`git stash`

and and then go to master branch whenever I do again

`git stash pop`

in the feature branch, if I go back again to master branch I am transferring the changes as well again. How can I leave the changes in the current branch, without a commit, and go to master branch to get the clean state from the master branch, so that I can create a new feature branch from that state?

Comment: Why not commit? It's not like you can't undo it

Answer (score 0):

Stash the changes of `feature` branch. Checkout to `master` then, create a new branch (say, `feature2`).

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git add -A
$ git stash                 # save all changes in a other box instead of working tree

$ git checkout master       # checkout to master
$ git status                # should have no local changes 

$ git checkout -b feature2  # create & checkout a new branch feature2 = master
$ git log                   # same history as master
```

The changes saved in `stash` are independent. So, in any branch: `git stash pop` would back the last stash changes in the current branch.